# How do I prove this Diophantine equation has no solutions?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime number.

Prove that  $x^2+2y^2=pz^2$ has no solutions in natural numbers with $x, y, z$ pairwise coprime and $y$ even unless $p\equiv 1$ (mod 8).

I don't understand how to utilise modular arithmetic in answering this equation, a detailed answer would be much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

Assume we had a solution of the specified form.

As $y$ is even (by assumption) $y^2$ is divisible by $4$ and $2y^2$ is divisible by $8$.  Hence, $\mod (8)$ the left hand of your equation is congruent to $x^2$.  It follows that any solution in integers would give a solution to $$x^2\equiv pz^2\mod (8)$$

As $z$ is odd (the three terms are meant to be relatively prime) we can divide by it to deduce that $p$ is a square $\mod (8)$.  But the only odd square $\mod (8)$ is $1$ so $p\equiv 1\mod (8)$